# MongoDB keysExamined:return Ratio

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

In MongoDB, we use aggregate and $group if we want to get count of some action. Suppose, we  have to get total number of deposits users have done in last 2 months then we use $group and then $sum to get count. Now in MongoDB Atlas profiler, it shows that as a very time taking and intensive operation. Because it scans keys of 2 months' data and return only 1 document(count). So is this a good way to get count or not?

Answer (score 0):

If your query is "get *total number* of deposits for a set of users between two dates where that set can be *all* users" **and** deposits is a collection with a field `user` or similar then you do not need `$group`.  Simply `count()` the filtered set:

```
db.deposits.find({$and:[
    {"user":{$in: [ list ]}},
    {"depositDate":{$gte: startDate}},
    {"depositDate":{$lt: endDate}}
]}).count();

or with the aggregation pipeline:

db.deposits.aggregate([
    {$match: {$and:[
        {"user":{$in: [ list ]}},
        {"depositDate":{$gte: startDate}},
        {"depositDate":{$lt: endDate}}
    ]}},
    {$count: "n"}
]});
```

Note you should be using a real datetime type for 'depositDate' -- not a string, not even ISO 8601 -- to facilitate more sophisticated queries involving dates.